# Can a WebLogic Singleton Service be used for wait/notify?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic

We have an app which maintains a `HashMap` in memory keyed by specific user IDs and had values representing certain system events. The basic functionality is that the user makes a request to the web server which checks the `HashMap` for any events keyed by their ID otherwise waits for a short amount of time on the `HashMap` until they either time out or a `notify` is executed on the `HashMap` which wakes the client up and immediately processes the event.

This was working fine in a single server environment but we are moving to a clustered environment and unsure of the best way to handle this particular piece.

Thinking we need to utilize database to queue up these events and lose that instant callback effect from `wait/notify` unless it is possible to somehow achieve that using the Singelton Service feature. Using Singleton Service would we be able to wait on an object from one server and get notified by a thread on the other server in the cluster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you use JMS for that. JMS is cluster-friendly and also can be configured to persist the events either in a file storage or database. Also you can select from 2 models: queue or topic depending on how your users need to be handled.

Comment: Yeah I was just thinking about that actually! Great suggestion! Now the only tricky part is that who publishes the events? I could have it sort of distributed where each server maintains its own service which initiates the code listening for events or perhaps this is where weblogic's singleton service could come into play where it could be centralized to one service that handles listening for the events and publishes?

Comment: I guess the process/component that fills the HashMap should now be responsible for firing JMS events/messages. Maybe if you could give a bit more details of what are those events and what is the expected bahvoir for the user, then it would be easier to give an advice.

Comment: The component which filled the HashMap is an open RMI connection to an external service. A new connection would be opened and maintained for each user. The component listens for events through that connection and populates/notifies the HashMap upon receiving an event which should then float down to the user if they are currently waiting or will be queued there until next time they check.